# transform pandas.Dataframe.ix in the new version of pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hello I am entered to update a code that used pandas 0.23.4
the line data ['dt'] = pd.DatetimeIndex (data.ix [:, 0]) brings me errors after upgrading pandas and python. According to research, this function (pandas.dataframe.ix) has been removed.
Which method can be used to replace it?
Basically what the code does, it does mean values per hour, which it writes to a new folder

```
import pandas as pd
from msvcrt import getch
from os import listdir

#reading file and user input
file_name = [filename for filename in listdir() if (".csv" or ".txt") in filename]

if not file_name:
    print("\nThere are no .csv files in folder")
    print(listdir())
else:
    for file in file_name:

        print("\nParsing {}".format(file))

        typ = file[-4:] #get extension of file

        if (typ == ".csv"):
            data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', encoding='utf-8', skiprows = 2)
            #subcase for different type of separators
            if len(data.columns) == 1:
                data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', skiprows = 2)

        else:
            data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', encoding='utf-16', skiprows = 2)
            if len(data.columns) == 1:
                data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', encoding='utf-16', skiprows = 2)


        data['Valeur'] = data['Valeur'] / 1000
        data['dt'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data.ix[:, 0])
        data = data.set_index(data['dt']).tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert("Europe/Paris")
        data['Valeur'].resample('1h').mean().to_csv("output//{}_0.csv".format(file[:-4].split(".")[0]))

print("\nPress any key (other than ALT) to exit")
getch()
```

data in the initial file:
[image: data in the initial file]

Final result:
[image: final Result]

Comment: Use `iloc` instead `ix`

Comment: i did it, i have this error 
"TypeError: [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
 datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 10, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))...."

Comment: Problem is with `data['dt'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data.ix[:, 0])` converted to `data['dt'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data.iloc[:, 0])` ?

Comment: yes!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/SMSARR/Desktop/Codes python capitole/Reshaper/reshaper.py", line 36, in <module>
    data['dt'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data.iloc[:, 0])
...
    raise TypeError(result)
TypeError: [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
 datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 10, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))...
 datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 31, 23, 40, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
 datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 31, 23, 50, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))]

Comment: One idea, how working `data['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(data.iloc[:, 0])` ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/SMSARR/Desktop/Codes python capitole/Reshaper/reshaper.py", line 37, in <module>
    data = data.set_index(data['dt']).tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert("Europe/Paris")
  ...
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex

Comment: Not idea what is problem, so reopened.

Comment: when i change ix to iloc here: monthed = df.ix[df["month of year"] == month] to  HPE_monthed = df.iloc[df["month of year"] == month]     i have thi error: ValueError: iLocation based boolean indexing cannot use an indexable as a mask.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution

```
import pandas as pd
from msvcrt import getch
from os import listdir

#reading file and user input
file_name = [filename for filename in listdir() if (".csv" or ".txt") in filename]

if not file_name:
    print("\nThere are no .csv files in folder")
    print(listdir())
else:
    for file in file_name:

        print("\nParsing {}".format(file))

        typ = file[-4:] #get extension of file

        if (typ == ".csv"):
            data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', encoding='utf-8', skiprows = 2)
            #subcase for different type of separators
            if len(data.columns) == 1:
                data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', skiprows = 2)

        else:
            data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', encoding='utf-16', skiprows = 2)
            if len(data.columns) == 1:
                data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', encoding='utf-16', skiprows = 2)


        data['Valeur'] = data['Valeur'] / 1000

        data['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(data.iloc[:, 0],utc=True)

        data = data.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(data['dt'])).tz_convert("Europe/Paris")



        data['Valeur'].resample('1h').mean().to_csv("output//{}_0.csv".format(file[:-4].split(".")[0]),header=False)
        print("fin de Reshaper, ciao!")

print("\nPress any key (other than ALT) to exit")
getch()
```